# Why didn't my meta question show associated question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, duplicate-questions, meta

Okay, this is getting really meta here, as this is a meta question about a question about meta, but bear with me...

I just asked [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/wheres-my-association-bonus-closed) question; it was closed as a dupe of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/rep-bonus-missing) question.  No problem with that; I'm all for dupes being closed.  However, here's the real question; when I went to ask the question, the only question in the Related Questions list that came up was the originating question from Jeff announcing the association bonus.  Is there a problem with related question searching, or is this a hole in the searching algorithm, or what?

Comment: It should be noted that these two questions were asked 5 hours apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Related Question will work best when there are more questions (as on StackOverflow)

It'll also be less effective on Meta, because there are generally so few words in common.. For example, there's plenty of keywords in common between "Generate RSS feed in Erlang" and "Erlang RSS feed generation", but not so much between something like "Why was my question deleted" and "Is deletion really necessary in this case?"

Comment: Perhaps the question search could treat *delete*, *deleting*, and *deletion*, as the same thing. *I think this is how Google treats them.*

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming  \o/

Answer (score 1):

I just clicked on your question and on the very top of the Related Questions is the "Rep Bonus Missing" question.

Comment: Okay; however, as I said, it wasn't there when I went to ask the question.

Comment: I just tried out what you said and saw the same thing. I would imagine this is a whole in the searching algorithm because if you type in anything like "rep bonus" in the question string, you'll likely find the question you are talking about (which I tried in a few different ways).

Comment: That should be "hole in the searching algorithm"

Comment: The point wasn't that it wasn't possible to find the question; the question was a meta question about a possible hole in the searching algorithm (which it seems like somebody might want to fix or investigate or something like that).